# Delete or filter Google Sheets row if it does not contain a string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet containing duplicate rows. The duplicate rows do not contain some variation of the string "All stories" (sometimes written as "all stories" or "All Stories"

I want to delete or filter the rows that do not contain the phrase "All stories"

So far I've put together a script that DOES delete the rows containing the phrase "All Stories"

But I haven't been able to figure out how to delete the rows if they do not contain the phrase

Here's what I have so far:

```
function readRows() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();

 var rowsDeleted = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

 var row = values[i];

 if (row[2].indexOf("(all stories)") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 } else if (row[2].indexOf("(All Stories)") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 } else if (row[2].indexOf("(All stories)") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }
 }
};
```

There are no error messages. It works just fine, it's just not the correct script! Any ideas how to make sure that the script deletes the rows that do not contain the string?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if the index is above  -1, you just need to check if the index is exactly -1, which means that the row does not contain the string.

Theres also no need to do 3 different checks, if you convert the row to lowercase first.

```
function readRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();

    var rowsDeleted = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
        var row = values[i];

        if (row[2].toLowerCase().indexOf("(all stories)") == -1) {
            sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
            rowsDeleted++;
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I was trying to exclude the first row, but:

sheet.getDataRange(C2:C200);

Didn't seem to work